# How to make a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn expand the dropdown to the left?

Tags: .net, drop-down-menu

I've got a `DataGridViewCobmoboxColumn` that has to be on the far right side of the screen. The items in the cell are wider that the cell width, so the dropdown list is also wider than the cell, so the user can see what top select. When the list drops down, the right side of the dropdown is not visible, and thus the scroll bar is also not visible. The users think there are only 7 items to choose from, when there are actually many.

Since this has to be on the right side, is there any way to anchor the dropdown to the right of the cell and expand to the left?

We're using .Net 2.0 for this project. Since we're coding in both VB and C#, I'm not too concerned about an answer being language specific. I'll take anything...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you need to auto-size the width so that things show up?
[I found a post on how to do that on MSDN.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/a3cab53b-8c03-4f43-83ac-808dc3751db9/)

Comment: Back in 2008 Stancliff said "Thanks for taking the time to answer, but making the dropdown wide enough is not a problem. The issue is that the dropdownlist is wider than the cell. It's anchored to the left cell edge and expands past the right cell edge - and thus off the screen.

What I need is to be able to anchor the dropdown to the right edge of the cell and have it expand past the left cell edge."

Answer (score 0):

I understand the question is old, but:

The best solution would be using something like `ToolStripDropDownDirection.AboveLeft`
*But as far as I see from source code there is nothing like this.*

So another approach could be setting values of DropDownWidth/MaxDropDownItems depending of position of the combobox from the right/bottom side of the screen.
*But this does not work because dropdown cannot be smaller than the cell.*

So you could try

- using refactoring to fix the control's behavior (low chance);
- forbidding moving the window (programmatically) close to the right edge of the screen;
- using your own control (override or write your own DataGridViewComboBoxColumn class) or buy custom grid.